# Quote Item, Configurable Product, Info_BuyRequest contains "uenc"

Tags: quoteitem, superattribute

While trying to load the simple product "child" of a configurable product in the order email item detail, I ran this code:

```
if ($_item->getProductType() == 'configurable') {
    $options = $_item->getProductOptionByCode('info_buyRequest');

    /** @var Mage_Catalog_Model_Product $_simpleProduct */
    $_simpleProduct = Mage::getModel('catalog/product_type_configurable')->getProductByAttributes($options['super_attribute'], $_product);
} else {
    /** @var Mage_Catalog_Model_Product $_simpleProduct */
    $_simpleProduct &= $_product;
}
```

...and got this error:

```
PHP Fatal error:  Call to a member function getBackend() on a non-object in [...]\app\code\core\Mage\Eav\Model\Entity\Abstract.php on line 816
```

It looks like that line tries to load an attribute, and can't find it, and then errors. The attribute code that it's trying to load is `uenc` which I can't find anywhere in `eav_attribute`. It turns out that `uenc` is a key in the array returned by `$options = $_item->getProductOptionByCode('info_buyRequest');` and I don't know why.

After some searching of the codebase, all I can find are various third party modules that all unset this array key as if it's consistently problematic, and a note about the value of this key being a base64 encoded product URL for the purchased product. (It looks like the constant `PARAM_NAME_URL_ENCODED` is actually used when this data is being added.)

Does anyone know what this is here for, and why it breaks `getProductByAttributes()`? It seems like I'm not the first developer to run into this issue.

Comment: I'm curious about this field I suspect (as of doing zero research on this so far) that it is security related (add to cart form origin) or helps with redirecting users.

Comment: Not sure the purpose but it is indeed the base64 encoded product URL.